# Would you use "that" or "it" in this situation?

Tags: pronouns

Could you tell me which sounds better?

Let's say you are  at a restaurant.You ask:

> What's today's special?
>   The server answers, It's grilled steak. It comes with mashed potatoes and green beans.

Then would you say ,"I'll have that." or "I'll have it."?
Which is correct or is it OK to use both?

Comment: As a learner, I think **that** because you are referring to a source or you are talking about a topic already discussed.

Comment: I'll have **that** please. I wouldn't say "it".

Comment: Do I understand correctly that's because the server's comment is not just one sentence? .If the server's reply is shorter like, " It's grilled steak.", then is it OK to say ,"I'll have it."?

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct. Just slightly different intonation. Personally, I would probably say "I'll have it".

Comment: I'd always use "that" in this context - i.e. the waiter tells you the special, and you refer to the thing he just said, "that"

Comment: "I'll have it" _might_ indicate you are a bit reluctant - maybe there's nothing better. But that depends on your tone of voice. Note that "it" will always be unstressed in this, but "I'll have that" will usually have stress on "that", and is more enthusiastic about the choice.

Comment: "that depends on your tone of voice." - exactly. A very important aspect of live conversation. People will easily forgive you your grammar mistakes but they won't forgive you the tone. :)

Comment: Thanks, now I understand the tone of voice is really important. Being nice to other people means you respect them.